# JUnit 5 - Empty test suite in IntelliJ IDEA when using JUnit Jupiter engine

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-test, junit5

How to execute All Suite tests with JUnit 5 in IntelliJ IDEA v2016.2.2?

I get *Empty test suite* running this code:

```java
import org.junit.platform.runner.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.runner.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@IncludeEngines("junit-jupiter")
@SelectPackages("<eu...package>") //I confirm that <eu...package> is ok.
public class AllTests {
}
```

I receive:

```
INFORMAZIONI: Discovered TestEngines with IDs: [junit-jupiter, junit-vintage]
Empty test suite.
Empty test suite.

[root]
JUnit Jupiter
JUnit Vintage
```

**OR**

```java
import eu.....services.ServiceTest;
import eu.....repository.DAOTest;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        ServiceTest.class,
        DAOTest.class
})
public class AllTests {
}
```

I receive:

```
INFORMAZIONI: Discovered TestEngines with IDs: [junit-jupiter, junit-vintage]
Empty test suite.

[root]
|+--JUnit Vintage
|   +--eu.....AllTests
|+--JUnit Jupiter
```

I was able to run suite with JUnit 4, but it doesn't work with JUnit 5.

Comment: In order to properly assess why your test suite is empty, we would have to see the source code of at least one of the test classes in package `<eu...package>`. For example, we would have to see that you are using the correct annotations and that test methods are annotated/declared correctly.

Comment: @SamBrannen, the methods are currently annotated with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`. If I put `org.junit.Test` than it is Vintage, it works if I put Suite.class, but it is Vintage. I asked suite execution with JUnit5 (Jupiter). As confirmation, test suite is empty also in your library when you execute the test class `SpringExtensionTestSuite`.

Comment: If you `git clone git@github.com:sbrannen/spring-test-junit5.git`, `cd spring-test-junit5`, run `gradlew eclipse`, and import the project into Eclipse, I promise you that `SpringExtensionTestSuite` executes fine and is not empty.

Comment: Thus, you must be doing something incorrectly, but I cannot really help you much further without seeing what is actually going wrong.

Comment: Long story, short: it's probably easiest if you create a simple project that reproduces the problem you're encountering and publish that in your GitHub repository. Then we can literally "check it out". ;)

Comment: @SamBrannen, well, I may create the sample project, but I use IDEA, not Eclipse.

Comment: After further investigation, I now assume that this is perhaps a _bug_ in IDEA. I will post back here with additional information later.

Comment: Can you please let us know exactly which version of IDEA you are using? It is **very** important for both the JUnit team and the IntelliJ team to know. So, thanks in advance!

Comment: @SamBrannen, IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.1 - Build #IU-162.1447.26

Comment: Thanks for letting us know the version of IDEA, and if you _accept_ my answer, I'd be grateful. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short Answer**

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2, it is currently not possible to execute a test class annotated with `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` within the IDE.

**Long Answer**

Based on the behavior you reported, after some painstaking investigative work, I believe I have the answer to your question...

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 which has built-in support for JUnit 5, then the following is what is happening.

1. IDEA launches the JUnit Platform via the `Launcher` API, selecting the test class annotated with `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` (let's call it `TestSuite`).
2. The `Launcher` detects both the `junit-jupiter` and `junit-vintage` `TestEngine` implementations.
3. The JUnit Jupiter engine ignores `TestSuite` since it is technically not a JUnit Jupiter test class.
4. The JUnit Vintage engine also ignores `TestSuite` since it is annotated with `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)`.
5. The end result is that neither registered test engine claims that it can run the `TestSuite` class.

The non-intuitive part is that the JUnit Vintage engine ignores `TestSuite`, when it in fact looks like a JUnit 4 based test class since it's annotated with `@RunWith()`. The reason it is ignored is to avoid infinite recursion, which is explained in the source code for [DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/r5.0.0-M2/junit-vintage-engine/src/main/java/org/junit/vintage/engine/discovery/DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java#L53-L71):

```java
if ("org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform".equals(runnerClass.getName())) {
    return null;
}
```

The fact that the above code returns `null` in such scenarios results in an *empty suite*.

Of course, it would certainly be better if the user were informed of such scenarios -- for example, via a log statement. I have therefore opened issues for both [JUnit 5](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/476) and [IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160253) to improve the usability in such scenarios.

On the plus side, since you're using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2, you don't need to use the test suite support. Instead, you can simply right-click on `src/test/java` in the project view in IDEA and select `Run 'All Tests'`, and that will run all your tests.

Regards,

Sam *(JUnit 5 core committer)*

Comment: OK, in the end you found out the reason. I couldn't imagine that it was the IDE. Good work Sam. I will run all tests from the folder then.

Comment: Thanks. My suite wasn't running. Right clicking to run all tests worked great.

Answer (score 3):

Additional to [Sam Brannen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39128861/3217378). I needed a TestSuit to setup the backend before running all test classes in a package. This is probably not possible via `Run 'All Tests'`.

But I think I found a good workaround for it. I came up with this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import your.other.package.test.classes.*;

public class TestSuit {
    @BeforeAll
    public static void setup(){}

    @Nested
    public class TestExtender extends MyTestClass {}
}
```

You could extend each test class from another package and add the `@Nested` annotation to it. It is not the best solution, but it is a workaround until IDEA or JUnit 5 find another solution for this cases.

Answer (score 0):

According to [junit official website](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-running):

> Just make sure that the junit-vintage-engine artifact is in your test runtime path. In that case JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 tests will automatically be picked up by the JUnit Platform launcher

Comment: it doesn't work your solution. On the methods of the test classes I have `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` and if execute tests for that class only it runs under engine Jupiter.
Also, if I put `org.junit.Test`, it means Vintage and indeed Suite execution is performed in Vintage! But this is not what we all want. I asked JUnit5 so with engine Jupiter, I think it's obvious, otherwise why to upgrade to JUnit5?
I mean [4.4.4. Test Suite] in the official website documentation.